# Android Google map api v2 how to get distance?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am recently doing a project about a running system. i want to get the distance traveled every 10 seconds or get the time traveled every 100 meters, as i wanna show the average speed of users in each period.And in every 100 meters or 10 seconds, the speed will be calculated by `s=v/t`, and the speed, time, and distance will all be sent to the database.

I wanna know

1. Can I use Google map api to get the time traveled every 100m?
2. Can i get the distance traveled every 10s?
3. in every 100 meters or 10 seconds, the speed, time, and distance will all be sent to the database.
   is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float[] distances = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(locationA.latitude, locationA.longitude,locationB.latitude, locationB.longitude,distances);

System.out.println("Distance: " + distances[0]);
```

> This is to find distance between two points with longitude and
>   latitude.So you have to save current location and after 10 sec u have
>   call this method again with saved location details and current
>   location.So u can get how much distance he traveled in that 10 sec.

Comment: *So you have to save current location and after 10 sec u have call this method again* that's not exact, OP wanna keem each 10 seconds **OR** 100m so, this method must be launched periodically every second or less and keep comparing to see if 100m passed, if no, after 10 seconds, store info....

Comment: Is there any library that I have to import?? As I am still finding methods to get real time info from google map ( distance and time).